# AMP pages with "change units" functionality for weather website

Tags: amp-html

I'm looking to have an AMP version of a niche weather website. Being weather related there is the issue of units - C/F, MPH / KMH etc.

This wouldn't be a problem except I have images and charts that are unit specific too. On the HTML version I can easily use a bit of JS to swap the units, however, I can't see a way of doing this on an AMP page except by linking to another page.

So, is there an AMP way of doing this or am I looking at just having a change unit link? Thanks

Comment: @can you please share the working example in html and js

Comment: @BachchaSingh not sure that would help as they are quite different - existing page uses JS powered charts and cookies to store unit preferences.
Having dug around a little I'm thinking of using a geo based unit selection and just having a link to the html site if the user wants to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a combination of [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) and [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list). The `amp-list` component will allow you to grab content from a JSON endpoint, which is where I assume is where your weather data is sourced from. You can then use `amp-bind` to toggle the visible state of the chart on the page depending on what unit of measurement is selected by the user. You can find more in-depth examples on the [AMP website](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-bind/), but here's a short sample which toggles a style on a div when you click a series of two buttons.

**Head:**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-state id="unitMeasurement">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "selected": "f",
      "f": {
        "style": "showF",
      },
      "c": {
        "style": "showC",
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

**Body**

```
<button class="btn"
  on="tap:AMP.setState({unitMeasurement: {selected: 'f'}})">
  Switch F
</button>

<button class="btn"
  on="tap:AMP.setState({unitMeasurement: {selected: 'c'}})">
  Switch C
</button>

<p [class]="unitMeasurement[unitMeasurement.selected].style"
  class="measurement">Units.</p>
```

Comment: Not using a JSON feed but amp-bind looks perfect having checked the docs and example here: https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-bind/source/